# Optaplanner Joiners.equal not using .equals?

Tags: java, optaplanner

Im defining a Constraint im my OptaPlanner project (using Constraint-Stream-API) starting in the following way:

```
factory.from(Lesson.class)
        .join(Lesson.class, equal(Lesson::getTimeslot, Lesson::getTimeslot))...
```

In the Class `Timeslot` i have overridden the `equals()`-method. 
To me it seems however that Joiners.equal doesnt use this equals Method to compare the timeslots, because i get different result using the following code:

```
 factory.from(Lesson.class).join(Lesson.class)
        .filter((l,m) -> l.getTimeslot().equals(m.getTimeslot())
```

Does anyone know on what basis `Joiners.equal` does its comparison?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, if we can reproduce it. Might you have a simple reproducer for us so we can verify easily and we can fix it quickly? **Do note that we expect you to adhere to the Java `equals/hashCode` contract, as defined by the Java Language Spec.**

Comment: Please copy paste your Timeslot's equals and hashcode methods in the question, to rule out that possibility.

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet It turned out that I violated the equals/hashCode contract. When I correct my hasCode()-method it works fine. Thx for the quick help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Joiners.equal` relies on `equals()` **and `hashCode()`** both fullfilling the Java equals/hashCode contract, as defined by the Java Language Spec.